# How to Switch Between Operating Systems Without Rebooting?

Tags: lubuntu

How to Switch Between Operating Systems Without Reboot?

Comment: Operating Systems relies on kernel to interact with hardware. That is Kernel is the very first thing which gets transferred into RAM. Different OS have different kernel. For example, Linux kernel is very much different from Windows NT kernel. And you can't handle Windows system calls from Linux kernel unless you're "virtualizing" things. If you don't want to reboot system to change OS, I'd recommend to use VM(s) but that of-course limit some functionalities.

Answer (score 2):

Use a hypervisor. Either a hardware or a software version.

> A hypervisor, also known as a virtual machine monitor, is a process that creates and runs virtual machines (VMs). A hypervisor allows one host computer to support multiple guest VMs by virtually sharing its resources, like memory and processing.
>
> Generally, there are two types of hypervisors. Type 1 hypervisors, called “bare metal,” run directly on the host’s hardware. Type 2 hypervisors, called “hosted,” run as a software layer on an operating system, like other computer programs.

The obvious method would be to install Windows inside Ubuntu using VirtualBox or VMWare.

Answer (score 1):

Operating Systems relies on kernel to interact with hardware. That is kernel is the very first program which is loaded into the memory right after the bootloader.

From [Kernel - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)):

> It handles the rest of startup as well as input/output requests from software, translating them into data-processing instructions for the central processing unit. It handles memory and peripherals like keyboards, monitors, printers, and speakers.

Different OSes have different kernel. For example, Linux kernel is very much different from Windows NT kernel. And you can't handle Windows system calls from Linux kernel unless you're "virtualizing" or translating things. If you don't want to reboot system to change OS, I'd recommend to use VM(s) but that of-course limit some functionalities.

---

#### Further Reading:

- [What happens when we turn on computer? - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-happens-when-we-turn-on-computer/)
- [System Call - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)
- [Kernel - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system))
- [Comparison of operating system kernels - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_operating_system_kernels)